# Jupyter Notebook Unable to Load Module mlwpy

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am completely new to programming in general and I do not understand very much about computers. A very similar question was asked previously, however I do not understand anything what was said.

Background: I am attempting to run the first line of code as described in the book Machine Learning with Python for Everyone by Mark Fenner on the Jupyter browser notebook.

**This is the code:**

```
In [1]: 

  from mlwpy import* 

  %matplotlib inline
```

**Running the code returns this error:**

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-3489a3655c97> in <module>
----> 1 from mlwpy import *
      2 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mlwpy'
```

From my understanding we need a module mlwpy.py and this module can be found at this link thanks to the author of the book here; https://github.com/mfenner1/mlwpy_code/blob/master/mlwpy.py

However, I do not understand what exactly I am supposed to do with this information. Someone mentioned **putting the file in the same directory as our Jupyter notebook.**

This is where I am confused, what does that mean exactly? I copied and pasted the text onto Jupyter and then saved it as mlwpy.ipynb in the binder, however the problem continues to remain the same.

If someone could explain step by step what I need to do, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mfenner1/mlwpy_code/master/mlwpy.py and put it in the same directory as your Jupyter notebook. The downloaded file should be named as mlwpy.py.

Comment: Save as mlwpy.py as cmbfast said. For additional context, a .py file is a python file, it has plain text code that runs from top to bottom (and often does things like set up other functions that will be useful to you). A .ipynb file is an IPython Notebook file, which has the multiple cells and output formatting that you're used to with Jupyter notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

`mlwpy` is not a Python's built-in library, nor an external library you can install with `pip` or `conda`. It is a custom python file you would like to import.

To run `from mlwpy import *`, you need to have a python script named `mlwpy.py` in the same directory as your Jupyter notebook file.

So download [raw.githubusercontent.com/mfenner1/mlwpy_code/master/mlwpy.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mfenner1/mlwpy_code/master/mlwpy.py) and put it in the same directory as your Jupyter notebook. The downloaded file should be named as mlwpy.py.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to check that you're in the correct working directory if running Jupyter. You can `import os` and `print(os.getcwd())` to see if you're in the right place. If not, either put the file in the working directory, or `cd` to the correct working directory before launching Jupyter.